# GWT: can I create a style which depends on Image injected into Widget?

Tags: css, gwt

I have created a GWT widget which is button. The button has two states: up and down. I want to change the image (icon) on the top of the button depending on the state of the button.

I thought the best way for this is to create separate style for both button states:

```
.buttonStateDown {
   color: red;
   background: ... here should be icon ImageResource. how to specify it? ...
}

.buttonStateUp {
   color: black;
   background: ... here should be icon ImageResource. how to specify it? ...
}
```

But I cannot figure how should I specify the backgrounds of these classes which are the icons of my button?

There can be several instances of my button with different icons. Consequently I cannot hardcode image resource into that 2 styles. I should inject them while creating the button. Indeed,  I can inject ImageResources via constructor or via setters. But the question is: how can I pass that resources to the styles I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suspecting you need GWT [PushButton](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PushButton.html).

Don't create any custom buttons and create `PushButton`.And use the constructor

```
PushButton(Image upImage, Image downImage, ClickHandler handler);
```

Comment: Thanks, Baadhah, I already tried this and here is a problem I have encountered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548465/gwt-how-can-i-add-uibinder-xml-layout-to-my-widget

Answer (score 3):

Please correct me weather i am write or wrong ,
If you are looking like on Button Mousedown handler you are setting its state to down and MouseUp handler you are setting its state to up then i suggest you that in gwt there is PushButton is there,
you can use ex:

```
PushButton pushBtn = new PushButton();
pushBtn.getUpFace().setImage(new Image(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/images/1.png"));
pushBtn.getDownFace().setImage(new Image(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/images/2.png"));
```

now when you mousedown on button then it shows 2.png.

Comment: Thanks Vikash! I have tried PushButton but encountered this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548465/gwt-how-can-i-add-uibinder-xml-layout-to-my-widget