# GWT: How can I add UiBinder xml layout to my Widget?

Tags: gwt

I have a button which is a direct descendant of GWT `PushButton`. I want to add UiBInder xml layout to my button to simplify its design. I have created `MyButton.ui.xml` and I have the following contents of `MyButton`:

```java
class MyButton extends PushButton 
{

interface UI extends UiBinder<Widget, MyButton>
{
}

private static final UI ui = GWT.create(UI.class);

@UiConstructor
public MyButton() {
        super();
        ui.createAndBindUi(this);
}

(...)

}
```

The problem is that my button is not rendered. GWT creates some div and places input element inside, but the layout I have created inside my uibinder xml file is not applied. Where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you annotating your fileds with @UiField ?

Comment: Yes, of course. If I need them inside the java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure, but, may be it's because you don't implement the asWidget() method:

```
@Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    return widget;
}
```

where widget is declared:

```
private final Widget widget;
```

and initialized in you constructor as:

```
widget = ui.createAndBindUi(this);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To directly respond to your question, the xml have to look like (with the necessary adjustments):

```xml
<ui:image field='downButton'/>
<g:PushButton ui:field='pushButton' enabled='true'>
  <g:upFace>
    <b>click me</b>
  </gwt:upFace>
  <g:upHoveringFace>
    <b>Click ME!</b>
  </gwt:upHoveringFace>

  <g:downFace image='{downButton}'/>
  <g:downHoveringFace image='{downButton}'/>
</g:PushButton>
```

See http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.html for the syntax.
Then into your `MyButton` you should use a method marked with `@UiFactory` in order to pickup the proper instance to supply the `UiBinder` `GWT.create()`.

```java
@UiFactory
DialogBox thatsJustMe() {
  // UiBinder will call this to get a PushButton instance.
  return this;
}
```

Anyway, you cannot change the structure of the widget. You are bound to its definition.